# Devise authentication registration new and create url are different by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have the following routes:

```
cancel_user_registration GET    /signup/cancel(.:format) devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /signup(.:format)        devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /signup/signup(.:format) devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /signup/edit(.:format)   devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /signup(.:format)        devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /signup(.:format)        devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /signup(.:format)        devise/registrations#destroy
```

I have used custom routing in route.rb file as:

```
devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', registration: 'signup', sign_up: 'signup'}
```

Problem with the above route is if I submit registration form with empty fields (`URL is localhost:3000/signup/signup`)  the page redirects to `location:3000/register`. Here it is showing the error messages. How do I redirect the same page if error found in form?

Updated routes:

```
cancel_user_registration GET    /cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /                        devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /signup(.:format)        devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /                        devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /                        devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /                        devise/registrations#destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try this.

```
     devise_for  :users,
                  :path => 'secure',
                  :path_names => {
                      :sign_in => 'login',
                      :sign_out => 'logout',
                      :sign_up => 'signup'
                  }
      resources :users
```

I am not sure you can name registrations and signup the same name

Comment: Tried with different name too for signup and registrations

Comment: This is the standard controller, having a look to see how you can solve this problem. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb